Getting error , Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in GIT CI/CD pipeline
I am working on migration project from angular 13 to 18.
Everything works well in local from scratch including cypress testcase.
But when I check in GIT CI/CD pipeline, it gives below error
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

In Cypress testcase I am using mock data and not sending any header as well.
How to trace actual error from where it comes or solve?
Note: In my app, there is no any API call in node.js
angular testcases using ng test working well. Issue is in CICD only

This question is similar to: ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, error seems same. But my app is in angular and I am using Http services for API calls.
In cypress testcase I am not calling any API I am just intercepting and mocking.
In local it works well for all scenarios.
